# Carousel Broken after WordPress Migration

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, carousel

After updating the WordPress and Site URLs (Settings - General), the images inside carousels went blurred (and reduced in size).

To rule out migration-related issues, I have tried 
1) migrating with All-in-One Migration Plugin, and 
2) migrating with cPanel-WordPress Tools-Backup. 
In both attempts, using Search and Replace plugin, I verified all image-links are updated and links in database are revised.

To rule out SSL-related issues, I have tried
3) Updating WordPress Address and Site URL (without SSL - http) 
4) Updating WordPress Address and site URL (with SSL - https)
Both break the carousel

To rule out image-related issues, I have tried 
5) regenerating thumbnails, and 
6) uploading fresh images.
7) Verify permissions (755) on /uploads folder

Finally, I have also tried 
8) using a different plugin (Meta Slider) for carousels. This broke the site's home page and I had to restore a backup.

All the above - without the desired result, and the problem persists.

The [Shortcodes Ultimate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/) plugin (carousel provider) [documentation](http://docs.getshortcodes.com/article/41-shortcodes-do-not-work) suggests that broken-carousels could be related to a Javascript issue. I am not a programmer and would really appreciate suggestions to fix this. Can someone please help?

The page I need help with: [Backpacking North East India](https://backpackingseries.com/2017/12/24/backpacking-north-east-india-now-amazon/)

Kind regards

Comment: the problem with images is in the some cache plugin. dig into cache plugins settings. here some help with jetpack: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/random-images-broken/

Comment: Thank you Samvel. Following that lead, I have posted a [question to JetPack](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/force-flush-photon-cache-for-broken-images-in-carousel-after-wordpress-migration/) to force flush Photon Cache. It seems strange that merely updating the WordPress Address and Site URLs should trigger this problem.

Comment: Update: Solved.

Shortcodes Ultimate plugin (while inserting carousels in a post) has a setting for ‘responsive’. Toggling it and tinkering with the width and height options offered a solution. Not sure what went wrong with it while updating the Site URLs. But this works for me. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome. you can answer to your own question, as what was wrong and how you solved that issue. after accept your answer as right. it may help somebody to fix his problmes in future

Answer (score 0):

I did not know I could answer my question here! Thank you [Samvel Aleqsanyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053001/samvel-aleqsanyan). Disclaimer: I am not a techie, but will try to explain nonetheless. Should someone face a similar problem, here's what I did to resolve it.

**Isolate the problem**: As you'd notice in the description above, I tried 7-8 things to fix it, ruling out issues with migration software/s, SSL, and images. To test the images, I published the images (that broke inside a carousel) on to a test page. The images published just fine without the carousel. That was a signal to probe the plugin I am using for carousels. I tried a different plugin (Meta Slider) but it broke the featured content on my home page.

**Shortcodes Ultimate Plugin**: This plugin is a very good option for someone like me (not a programmer). It seems lightweight and offers design options in an easy to understand format. After migration, it behaved as promised for all other components except carousels. So, changing the plugin at an advanced stage was not the best option.

**Change Plugin Configuration**: The plugin sets a carousel's default width to 200 and default height to 20. If you toggled the "responsive" to yes (my preferred setting in the dev env), it ignored the width and height parameters. But, when I updated the WordPress Address and Site URLs, something went wrong and the carousels broke. So, after carrying out the steps mentioned in the question and isolating the problem, I came back to Shortcodes Ultimate and tinkered with the default settings: toggled responsive to "No" and manually set the width and height. That gave me the different result - for the first time.

**Bigger Image Size**: While changing the default configuration worked, the carousel-images, when published, got smaller in size. So, I recreated all the carousel-linked images to a higher resolution (from 200x200 to 768x768).

I wonder why I did not think @ it sooner! Here's the page: [Backpacking North East India](https://www.backpackingseries.com/2017/12/24/backpacking-north-east-india-now-amazon/) Hope this answer helps someone else.

Cheers